# Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged.* classes in GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any problem with using classes in `com.google.appengine.repackaged.*` ?

I mean, it it an unofficial API, is it subject to change or could it be a source of future problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will (should?) work, but I believe the official line is that they aren't guaranteed to stick around in later versions of the SDK.  If you find yourself needing a package under `repackaged`, you should use the library directly, so you have more complete control over your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I think, but I'm afraid of that "SHOULD work".  I've not found any official pronouncement about it to be sure.  I am going to include my own library.